# Submitting a search query with ReactiveSearch

Tags: reactivesearch

I've been building a search UI with ReactiveSearch. I'm trying to figure out how to submit the actual search query. I've been using the DataSearch component because it comes with autocomplete baked in (just set it to true!). The autocomplete works fine. Suggestions are shown, I'm able to select them, BUT there are no actual search results when I select a suggestion by clicking on it or pressing enter.

Here is my DataSearch

```
<DataSearch
  placeholder="Search..."
  componentId="q"
  dataField={["firstname"]}
  queryFormat="or"
  className="navbar-search-box"
  icon={(<i className="fa fa-search fa-lg" style={searchIcon}></i>)}
  showIcon={true}
  iconPosition="right"
  URLParams={true}
  innerClass={{
    title: "text-title",
    input: "text-input",
    list: "text-item"
  }}
  react = {{
    "or": ["q"]
  }}
  onValueSelected={(value, cause, source) => {
    this.setState({redirect:true});
    }
  }
  onQueryChange = {
    (prevQuery, nextQuery) => {
    console.log('prevQuery', prevQuery);
    console.log('nextQuery', nextQuery);
    }
    }
    ...
```

I'm assuming I don't need to use their appbase-js library to submit a full-text search query to ES. I'm assuming the DataSearch component puts the query together as long as you have the `dataField` propery assigned a value.

I also get this error when I try to submit a query:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Maybe that has something to do with the search query not working? Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onQueryChange` is fired any time a query changes for the component. Here you would have to check the `cause` in `onValueSelected` and then handle the updated query. For example:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4p5177jw9)

```
<DataSearch
  ...
  onValueSelected={(value, cause, source) => {
    if (cause !== 'SUGGESTION_SELECT') {
      // use this.query
      console.log('use', this.query);
      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      });
    } else {
      this.valueSelected = true;
    }
  }}
  onQueryChange={(prevQuery, nextQuery) => {
    this.query = nextQuery;
    if(this.valueSelected) {
      // use this.query
      console.log('use', this.query);
      this.valueSelected = false;
      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      });
    }
  }}
/>
```

### Explanation

When the cause for value selection is not a suggestion selection (i.e. it could be enter key press) then `onQueryChange` would have already updated `this.query` which you can use directly in `onValueSelected`. However, if the cause for value selection was `SUGGESTION_SELECT`, the query would have to update after selection. In this case I'm just setting a flag `this.valueSelected`, to delegate the query handling logic, which is then read in `onQueryChange`.

In short for a suggestion selection, the flow goes from `onValueSelected` to `onQueryChange` and for other causes (including an enter key press), we would already have the query from `onQueryChange` in `this.query`, therefore it gets handled in `onValueSelected`. Hope this helps.

As for sending a search request its not necessary to use `appbase-js`, a simple `fetch` request would also work. If you're using `appbase-js` then you could use the `search` method to just simplify the API [docs](https://docs.appbase.io/javascript/api-reference.html#search).

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I tried the demo and when I select a suggestion from the dropdown - there are still no actual search results on the /search page... that is what I mean by no search results in my question. To that point, it sounds like I do need to actually submit the query myself via fetch/axios or appbase-js, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, in the demo I'm just rendering a sample search page. But after getting the query you could execute it and display the results.

Comment: thank you. You've been great with answering all my questions, thanks very much! I'm coming from Angular and trying to digest React and ReactiveSearch at the same time... learning as I go.

Comment: You're welcome. I love to help out people on SO in my spare time. All the best :)